# Box model only apply when container have a padding or a border?

Tags: html, css

Take a look at this two links:

http://jsfiddle.net/carloscalla/N8q27/10/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <h2>Subtitle</h2>
    </div>    

    <div id="container2">
        <p>Hola</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
h1
{
    background-color: green;

}
h2
{
    background-color: blue;

}
#container
{
    background-color: yellow;
    border: solid black 2px;
}
#container2
{
    background-color: orange;
    border: solid blue 2px;
}
```

Rendered:

[image: Rendered result of version 10]

http://jsfiddle.net/carloscalla/N8q27/11/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <h2>Subtitle</h2>
    </div>    

    <div id="container2">
        <p>Hola</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
h1
{
    background-color: green;

}
h2
{
    background-color: blue;

}
#container
{
    background-color: yellow;
}
#container2
{
    background-color: orange;
}
```

[image: Rendered result of version 11]

It is simple, when I apply border to the container, the child's padding is considered by the container, if I don't apply border(or padding works as well) it doesn't so when I apply background-color, there is a white space between the document objects.

Can anybody explain this? is there a way to solve it without applying padding or border to the container?

Comment: "*Take a look at this two links (sic)*" > **NO**. Post your code, don't point me towards unexplained **is.gd** links.

Comment: I hope you didn't use those links to avoid [the ban on jsfiddle links without code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code)...

Comment: I was new to stack overflow at that time. I didn't know there was a ban for that. I just noticed I wasn't able to post  with the jsfiddle links so I shortened them. I didn't realize I they can't be shown without code given in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [margin collapse](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins). Instead of applying a border, set `overflow: auto;`. This resolves margin collapse.

DEMO [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/N8q27/12/)

```
#container
{
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. By the way, if I set overflow: auto; doesn't it interfere with another property or can make some other properties behave different? or there is nothing to worry about. I am just keeping in mind the case of floating objects that cause them to behave different, just in case :D

Comment: It would not cause any issues in my experience.

Comment: Is there another way to deal with the margin collapse? like setting a transparent border or something like that? What is the most decent solution? :D

Comment: You could do it with transparent border. Some people do it by setting a `1px` border then `-1px` margin, this also works.

Answer (score 2):

That is due to [margin collapsing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) - in the first example the container holds two headers which each have default top/bottom margins of 16px, and because the top-margin of an in-flow block level element will always collapse with it's *first* in-flow block-level child, the `<h1>` margin is collapsing beyond the container.

When you add a border to the container, you are preventing margin collapsing.

From the 2.1 spec:

> The top margin of an in-flow block element collapses with its first in-flow block-level child's top margin if the element has **no top border**, no top [padding](http://jsfiddle.net/N8q27/13/), and the child has no clearance.

Comment: Maybe people that just want to bother. This is the correct answer as well as Vector's answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does it also apply for horizontal margins? in CSS2 it didn't

Comment: Margin collapsing only happens on vertical margins.